# Spring boot - multiple datasource failed to configure datasource url

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, jpa

My spring boot project has two datasource configurations for the databases `Akademiks & Options`, but if I run the code, I would get the exception `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.` However, when I removed the configuration for the options database from the application.properties, it worked well

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.akademiks.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.akademiks.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/akademiks?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.akademiks.username=root
spring.datasource.akademiks.password=root


spring.datasource.options.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.options.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/akademiksoptions?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.options.username=root
spring.datasource.options.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.database = mysql
```

AkademiksDbConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.resource.akademiks.dao",
 entityManagerFactoryRef = "akademiksEntityManagerFactory",
 transactionManagerRef = "akademiksTransactionManager")
public class AkademiksDbConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.akademiks")
    public DataSourceProperties akademiksDataSourceProperties() {
        
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.akademiks.configuration")
    public DataSource akademiksDataSource() {
        
        return akademiksDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        
    }
    
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "akademiksEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    akademiksEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        
        return builder
                .dataSource(akademiksDataSource())
                .packages(Mathematics.class)
                .packages(Chemistry.class)
                .packages(Physics.class)
                .build();
                
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager akademiksTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("akademiksEntityManagerFactory")
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean akademiksEntityManagerFactory
            ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(akademiksEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
    
}
```

OptionsDbConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.resource.akademiks.options.dao",
 entityManagerFactoryRef = "optionsEntityManagerFactory",
 transactionManagerRef = "optionsTransactionManager")
public class OptionsDbConfig {
    
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.options.configuration")
    public DataSourceProperties optionsDataSourceProperties() {
        
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.options.configuration")
    public DataSource optionsDataSource() {
        
        return optionsDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
        
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "optionsEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    optionsEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        
        return builder
                .dataSource(optionsDataSource())
                .packages(MathsOptions.class)
                .packages(ChemistryOptions.class)
                .packages(PhysicsOptions.class)
                .build();
                
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager optionsTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("optionsEntityManagerFactory")
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean optionsEntityManagerFactory
            ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(optionsEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.resource</groupId>
    <artifactId>akademiks</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>akademiks</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: When do you get this exception? During Test with @DataJpaTest?

Comment: No, not during a test. However, I've discovered the issue with my code - I should've removed a persistent bean I autowired in one of my service's constructor because it wasn't part of or defined in my multiple datasource configuration.